# Copy formats from an indirect cell

Tags: excel, vba, formatting

I managed to copy cell formats `within the same sheet` by using

```
Dim c As Boolean

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If c Then Exit Sub
    c = True
    f = Mid(Target.Formula, 2)
    Range(f).Copy
    Target.PasteSpecial xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme
    c = False
End Sub
```

But in `another sheet`, I use `=INDEX(Sheet1!$I$1:$J$255,MATCH(A4,Sheet1!$F$1:$F$255,0),1)` to get the value from `Sheet1`.

Now how can I copy the source format just like the cells in the same sheet would!?

I had tried everything in [Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&ei=-IFKXLuqCoqS8wXbvqMo&q=excel%20vba%20copy%20paste%20range%20value%20format&oq=excel%20vba%20copy%20&gs_l=psy-ab.1.0.0l6j0i203l4.763266.770929..774817...0.0..0.54.252.5......0....1..gws-wiz.......35i39.HCSVV6c_UkM) to no avail!

I even tried to make my own function and still failing to do so!!!

```
'(One variation)
Function CopyFrom(ByVal Cell)

    Dim r As Range

    Set r = Worksheets(Cell.Parent.Name).Range(Cell.address(External:=False))
    CopyFrom = r.Value2
    r.Copy
    Application.Caller.PasteSpecial xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme

End Function
```

I'm kind of at the end of my rope now!

Somebody PLEASE be so kind and teach me how to do it!

Much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the cell you want to copy is A1 on sheet called "another sheet".
Assuming you want to paste in cell A1 on sheet called "Sheet1".

```
option explicit
dim wb as workbook
dim wsSource as worksheet, wsDest as worksheet
dim Target As Range


Sub test()
set wb = thisworkbook
set wsSource = wb.Sheets("another sheet")
set wsDest = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set Target = wsDest.Range("A1")

    wsSource.Range("A1").Copy
    Target.PasteSpecial xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme
End Sub
```

Comment: you would need to adapt this code to match your specific needs, which I cannot seem to deduct from your original question.

Comment: This worked if it's a "direct reference". Where you know the source and target cell as "A1" or "D7". But if my reference is "indirect", such as my example above, it failed! Unless I could somehow get the direct link from my formulas! I'll see what I can do. Thanks!